# vb.net awesomium cancel request when url contains specific keyword

Tags: vb.net, awesomium, request-cancelling

im using awesomium and vb.net as a client side application for my web application. Can anyone say me how to cancel a request when a url contain a specific key word. for example , if my url contains view , then i need to cancel the request and download the pdf to local machine and view it with client pdf viewer. i had done the second part but i dont know how to cancel the the request.

using vb.net native webcontrol i have navigating event . but what it the event equivalent to this in awesomium

below is the code im using

```
Public Class ResourceInterceptor  Implements IResourceInterceptor
Public Function OnFilterNavigation(ByVal request As NavigationRequest) As Boolean Implements IResourceInterceptor.OnFilterNavigation
    If request.Url.ToString.Contains("ViewPdf") Then
        Path = ExtractPath(request.Url.ToString)
        openpdf(Path)
        Return False ' Cancel the request. 
    Else
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(request.Url.ToString)
        Return True
    End If
End Function

Public Function OnRequest(ByVal request As ResourceRequest) As ResourceResponse Implements IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest
    Return Nothing
End Function

End Class
```

Can any one say how to cancel a request when a url contain a specified text

Comment: i made a small mistake. to block any incoming request you have to return true and not false. now it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `Awesomium.Core.IResourceInterceptor` interface and attach it to your webcore session with `WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = new ResourceInterceptor();`

Here is a simple ResourceInterceptor in C#.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Awesomium.Core;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class ResourceInterceptor : IResourceInterceptor
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Not used.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
        {
             return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Optionally blocks any web browser requests by returning true when the URL contains "/view/".
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
        {
            return String.Contains(request.Url.AbsolutePath, "/ViewPdf/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time steve jansen.

Comment: @Yuvaraj if this solved your problem, can you please mark my answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: Steve Jansen , it is not working for me . i edited my Question , please say me where i made wrong .

Comment: I was testing for "/view/" originally. Updated to match against "/ViewPdf/".  Try this and set a breakpoint at the `OnFilterNavigation` method.   This should be hit many times as you load a page, returning true only for URLs containing "/ViewPdf/".  If not, you forgot to attach it to your session with `WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = new ResourceInterceptor();`

Comment: Steve thanks for your time. its now working. thanks for your help and time to put me on the right direction